# ¿Abrir un archivo .txt con pandas de un zip que la ruta varia de nombre?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

quisiera preguntar por la siguiente necesidad. Debo obtener información de un aplicativo, dicho aplicativo descarga la información  en una ruta (siempre la misma) en un carpeta comprimida .zip el cual contiene un .txt, esta carpeta y  archivo cada que ejecuto el informe adopta un nombre diferente.

Quiero saber la forma en que puedo abrir el txt, desde esa ruta sin importar el nombre de la carpeta comprimida .zip.

A continuación doy un ejemplo

```
fecha informe      ruta 
27/05/202021        C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Temp\archivo\99D6.zip
28/05/2021          C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Temp\archivo\105E6.zip
```

Es de anotar que hasta la subcarpeta "archivo", la ruta siempre es igual, varia es el nombre del comprimido .zip, y el archivo .txt tiene el mismo nombre del comprimido.

¿Hay una forma de leer este archivo de una manera programada con python y pandas?

Comment: podrias usar expresiones regulares, además no creo que pandas sea la mejor opcion para leer un `.txt` (aunque si se puede)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `pathlib` puedes obtener la lista de ficheros que hay en una carpeta dada, y combinando eso con una comprensión de listas en la que filtramos para quedarnos sólo con aquellos que terminan en `.zip`, podemos crear una lista con todos los ficheros zip contenidos en tu carpeta:

```
from pathlib import Path

ruta = r"C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Temp\archivo"
zips = [ f for f in Path(ruta).iterdir() if f.name.endswith(".zip") ]
```

Voy a suponer que de todos esos ficheros sólo te interesa el más reciente. Podemos entonces usar la función `max()` con la `key` apropiada para que ordene por fecha de modificación y quedarnos con el que tenga fecha mayor:

```
from os.path import getmtime
nuevo = max(zips, key=getmtime)
print(nuevo)
```

Una vez tenemos localizado el fichero zip en cuestión, podemos usar `zipfile` para abrirlo y para leer cualquier fichero que tenga dentro.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

z = ZipFile(nuevo)
name_txt = nuevo.name.replace(".zip", ".txt")
with z.open(name_txt) as f:
  content = f.read()
```

En este caso he leído el contenido del `txt` a la variable `content`, que será por tanto una cadena. Si el .txt contiene información estructurada que Pandas pueda leer (por ejemplo un csv), podrías haber escrito en cambio:

```
with z.open(name_txt) as f:
  df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias